# Ajax in Dropdown list of Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to sort my product list by name,rate,etc. using `DropDownList`

On change event of this dropdown list,i want to show sorted product list using ajax.

How it possible in ASP.net MVC(RAZOR)?

Comment: See my answer to a similar question here (you could either sort the data clientside, or retrieve it from the server, ready sorted): http://stackoverflow.com/a/8986889/234415