# binding collection using Model binding query

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model

I have a list of object as model. I have properties like Server, Database, User.

What i want is a dropdown with list of object bound to it and on the change of dropdown items, I have to populate the Database and User information in 2 different labels.

How can i achieve that using Model Binding ??

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand what do you mean when asking about 'using Model Binding'. But it can be done with jquery/javascript. You create dropdownlist on page and on change event send selected item to server and receive 'Database and User information'. Example using Ajax helper: [using ajax with dropdownlist mvc3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8986795/using-ajax-with-dropdownlist-mvc3/8986889#8986889)

Comment: Plz take a look at this for model biniding.

Comment: @SanjaySutar with such article, you will never understand model binding, read this articles [ASP.NET MVC Custom Model Binding](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=584) and [Understanding ASP.NET MVC Model Binding](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Understanding-ASP-NET-MVC-Model-Binding.aspx)  they are much better.