# MVC4 two controllers with a common partial view issue

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

[image: Mvc4 with 2 controllers]

From the image i try to load two controllers, on pageload Browse controller loads with 1 and 2 data from picture, when i want to select the date,it should load the dayselect controller data  in same page. How can i do this , My controllers are here

```
public ViewResult Browse(Int32 eventid) {
//code
return view(ef);
}

public ActionResult DaySelect(EventModel m) {
return view("_Common",k);
}
```

My viewModel for Browse Controller is Browse.cshtml

```
@model BrowseEventModel

<div class="Event_Name" id="id_name">@Model.EventName</div>

<div class="Event_loc" id="id_loc">@Model.EventLocation</div>

//In this view i have a widget which i load in partial view

<div class="yui3-g" id="bottom_container"> @{Html.RenderPartial("_Common");}

</div>
```

The partial view is _common.cshtml

```
@model BrowseEventModel
<select name="dayNo" id="dayNo">
@foreach (var s in Model.Dayselector) {
<option value = "@s.DayNo"> @s.DayDate.ToString("dd MMM yyyy")</option>
}
</select>
```

//View Model used for both browse and dayselect controller

```
@foreach(var e in Model.DisplayData){    
<ul id="ul-data">@e.dataName</ul>
<div id="ul-id">@e.dataid</div> 
}
```

When i select the date it should load data in same view page is it possible,i.e injecting view on runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AJAX to inject view at runtime. In your case, you are depending on the onchange event of a DropDownList. A question has already been asked with the same problem as yours. Try this: [using ajax with dropdownlist mvc3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8986795/using-ajax-with-dropdownlist-mvc3)

Comment: can you brief me! about ajax injecting at runtime